# Passing array state data up and over from child to sibling component by way of mutual parent leaves array short by one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, state

This `Footer` component creates an array. I'd like to make this array available in a sibling `Body` component. I'd like to do this by passing the `reminders` array variable up and over to the `Body` component by way of their mutual `Parent` component.

```
import './style.css'

function Footer({ linkToFooter }){
  const [reminder, setReminder] = useState("");  
  const [reminders, setReminders] = useState([]);

  const submitThis = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (reminder){
        let newReminder = {
          reminder: reminder,
          complete: false,
         };
         setReminders(prevRems => [...prevRems, newReminder])
         setReminder('');
     } else {
      setReminder("oops there's a problem");
    }
  };

  useEffect(
    () => { localStorage.setItem('reminders', JSON.stringify(reminders)); }, 
    [reminders]
  );

  console.log(reminders, "from Footer");

  return(
    <div className="rm-list-footer">
      <form onSubmit={submitThis}>
        <input 
          id='newReminder' 
          type='text'
          value={reminder}
          onChange={(e) => setReminder(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={() => linkToFooter(reminders)} type='submit'>+</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Footer;
```

This is the `Parent` function component that I'd like to be the segway between the two child components.

```
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Body from "./Body";

function RmList() {
  const [reminders, setReminders] = useState([])
  
  return(
    <div className="rm-list">
    <Header></Header>
    <Body reminders={reminders}></Body>
    <Footer linkToFooter={setReminders}></Footer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RmList;
```

Finally, my goal is to `console.log` the array in this sibling `Body` component every time the button in the `Footer` component is clicked. The problem is that the array that's logged in the `Body` is always one element behind what's logged in the `Footer` with every click.

```
import React from "react";

function Body({reminders}) {
  console.log(reminders, "from Body");

    return(
        <div className="rm-list-body"></div>
    );
}

export default Body;
```

After researching I thought my problem might have to do with changing this

```
setReminders([newReminder, ...reminders])
```

to this

```
setReminders(prevRems => [...prevRems, newReminder])
```

but that was to no avail as I can't pass `prevRems` to the parent.

Your help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: In your Parent component, you initialized reminders with the initial state as an empty array and just passed it to the Body component. There is no update in state, so you will always receive a blank value in Body.

Comment: Do you have some minimal reproducible code example? e.g. codesandbox or stackblitz?

Comment: Learn about lifting up state: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components

Answer (score 1):

If im understanding correctly, you want to be able to set reminders in one child and see reminders in a sibling. if that is correct, reminders as a state should only be in the parent. you can then pass the state and state-setter to the children and access them through props. by re-declaring "reminders" in the child you could have a conflict of state.

also, it is best practice to name your props being passed like this

`<Footer setReminders={setReminders}>`

so that on larger projects its easy to follow your prop's path

try

```
import './style.css'

CHANGE >>>> function Footer({  linkToFooter > setReminders }){
  const [reminder, setReminder] = useState("");  
REMOVE >>>> const [reminders, setReminders] = useState([]);

  const submitThis = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (reminder){
        let newReminder = {
          reminder: reminder,
          complete: false,
         };
         setReminders(prevRems => [...prevRems, newReminder])
         setReminder('');
     } else {
      setReminder("oops there's a problem");
    }
  };

  useEffect(
    () => { localStorage.setItem('reminders', JSON.stringify(reminders)); }, 
    [reminders]
  );

  console.log(reminders, "from Footer");

  return(
    <div className="rm-list-footer">
      <form onSubmit={submitThis}>
        <input 
          id='newReminder' 
          type='text'
          value={reminder}
          onChange={(e) => setReminder(e.target.value)}
        />
CHANGE >>>> <button onClick={() => linkToFooter > setReminders(reminders)} type='submit'>+</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Footer;
```

let me know if that has helped guide you in the right direction. and hopefully these little tricks will help you keep your code more readable. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you, after a little more tinkering I found that passing the `reminders` variable from the `Parent` component down along with the `setReminders` prop, in the way that you recommended, achieves my goal. (An error returned `reminders` as undefined otherwise.) A day's worth of effort has paid off thanks to the help of a kind community, thank you. :) @Nephter

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. happy coding